# Got stuck with re.findall function for regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have a string which looks something like

```
text = "customer: Anna Smith; payment: 123; date: 12-02-2020; customer: Jack; payment: 10.3; date: 20-03-2020"
```

Now I want to turn it into a list of tuples (which later I can use to create a dictionary):

```
[('customer', 'Anna Smith'),
 ('payment', '123'),
 ('date', '12-02-2020'),
 ('customer', 'Jack'),
 ('payment', '10.3'),
 ('date', '20-03-2020')]
```

I tried to use re.findall for this purpose in the following way:

```
re.findall(u'(\w+): (.+?);', text)
```

Of course it doesn't capture the last pair of a key and a value, because of the semicolon in the regular expression. I think that I need an if-else if operation here: if the parser encounters a semicolon, then it extracts the words, else it checks for a regular expression for EOL (`\Z`). Please, help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match the last one as well, use this pattern `(\w+): (.+?)(?:;|$)`

The only difference between this and your pattern is it will accept look for a match that ends in either `;` or `$` which is the end of line character.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0J7ZEm/3)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of matching the `;`, change `.+?` to `[^;]+` so it matches everything that isn't a `;`.

```
re.findall(r'(\w+): ([^;]+)', text)
```

Comment: doesn't work with ```ru```, changed it to ```r``` and it worked.

Comment: Turns out that in Python 3 strings are always Unicode, so `u` is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

To just keep it simple, we can also use the `split` function.

```
arr = text.split("; ")
result = []
for a in arr:
    _ = a.split(": ")
    result.append((_[0], _[1]))
```

Now the `result` list contains your desired output